# FTP Daemon that support TLS/SSL over FXP?

Tags: ftp

I'm searching an ftp daemon that can support SSL/TLS over FXP using CPASV (or/and) SSCN and whos name is not "glftpd" or "drftpd". Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The most recent versions of proftpd include mod_tls support for SSCN.